# What is the meaning of the $\phi$ symbol in calculus?

Tags: calculus, notation

My textbook shows the following step..

$$\large{F_{T}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{t|y|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}} dx \right) dy}$$

$$\large{=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}} \phi(t|y|)   dy}$$

What is the meaning of $\phi$, and what 'happened' in this step? I understand how to take integrals generally but I have never seen this, and I wasn't able to find an explanation online (I'm not quite sure what to search?).

Comment: It's just a shorthand for the integral in brackets. It's also known as the standard normal cumulative distribution in statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi(x)$ is simply shorthand for the cumulative normal density function. It is the integral of the Gaussian (normal) density from $-\infty$ to $x$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function